Origins of the use of matrices for the calculus of binary relations
Nowadays it's common to represent a binary relation $r$ (a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$) as a 0,1-matrix whose rows correspond to elements of $A$, whose columns correspond to elements of $B$, and whose entries equal 1 or 0 according to whether the associated ordered pairs do or do not belong to $r$; a virtue of this representation is that composition of relations corresponds to a modified form of matrix multiplication in which one operates on 0's and 1's using Boolean addition and Boolean multiplication (which are just like ordinary addition and multiplication except that $1+1=1$). This way of representing relations has even entered the undergraduate curriculum for computer science majors. But who first came up with it? I've read Vaughan Pratt's "Origins of the Calculus of Binary Relations" (http://boole.stanford.edu/pub/ocbr.pdf) but the essay does not treat that part of the story.

Prosser, R. T. (1959). Applications of Boolean matrices to the analysis of flow
diagrams. Proc. Eastern Joint Computer Conf., pp. 133-138 might be what you are looking for.

The question seems to contain numerous aspects.

When did boolean matrices first appear?

For this question I recommend the historical exposition:

Copilowish, I. M. (1948). Matrix development of the calculus of relations. The Journal of Symbolic Logic, 13(4), 193-203.


Matrix notation was applied to the logic of relations as long ago as
1870 by Peirce [..]


C.S. Peirce (1873) Description of a Notation for the Logic of Relatives, resulting from an Amplification of the Conceptions of Boole's Calculus of Logic. Memoirs of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences, 9:2, pp. 317-378.

Incidentally Jevons also uses matrix block style organization of boolean terms in 1864:

Jevons, W. S. (1864). Pure Logic: Or, The Logic of Quality Apart from Quantity; with Remarks on Boole's System and on the Relation of Logic and Mathematics. E. Stanford. (Link to 1892 reprint. See pp. 114ff.).

These ideas then trace into successively more modern understanding via Schroeder and Russell-Whitehead finding their way into lattice theory (see Birkhoff Lattice Theory 2nd Edition, compare Preface of the Second Edition first two paragraphs).
Of course part of the problem here is post-hoc recognition of something as a matrix. This can be traced back to the Greeks if one accepts truth tables as matrices (compare Bochenski (1961) History of Formal Logic. p. 115 crediting Philo).

How did boolean matrix multiplication enter computer science as a field?

I do believe that the paper by Prosser is a likely point of this transition.
Prosser, R. T. (1959). Applications of Boolean matrices to the analysis of flow diagrams. Proc. Eastern Joint Computer Conf., pp. 133-138.
It cites Copilowish (though without in-text reference and with a truncation on the name (Copi instead of Copilowish). It is an immediate precursor to Warshall, S. (1962). A theorem on boolean matrices. Journal of the ACM (JACM), 9(1), 11-12. This paper is a highly-cited paper as it is credited for being part of a now textbook algorithm named Floyd-Warshall (compare Cormen-Leiserson-Rivest-Stein). Copilowish does not claim novelty in content and says he followed Russell-Whitehead (p.26ff) but his contribution is to advance the content in concrete matrix form, leading to ease of application.
P.S. I seem to have typed this up in parallel to the Professor Propp's own answer, which comes to a similar conclusion.
P.P.S. Apparently the trunctation of name to Copi is unremarkable outside of bibliographical concerns.

The first to give a clear and modern exposition of this is Irving Copilowish in his article “Matrix Development of the Calculus of Relations” (Journal of Symbolic Logic Vol. 13, No. 4 (Dec., 1948), pp. 193-203); he writes that the matrix approach to the study of relations “was well known to both Peirce and Schroder”, though he adds that the approach “cannot be said to have been unobjectionably formulated by either of them.”

I do believe that in a certain sense this is a good answer. But there certainly are also some complications to this history. One complication is documented in Birkhoff, (1948) Lattice Theory 2nd Ed. (see preface and p. 209ff), which has these ideas, including the relationship to matrix algebras developed in a more abstract algebraic framework being at least contemporaneous if not outright predating Copilowish. The second complication is present in Copilowish who gives  F. I. Mautner (1946) credit for the more general idea of tensors over boolean algebras (matrices being a special case).
